# Como hacer que el resultado de x y no x1, c++

Tags: c++

Estoy desarrollando unos ejercicios basico y voy atorado en este, el programa me pide hacer que de un resultado de una variable x1 y que sea igual a nX pero si es 1 que solo se muestre x. Ejemplo

> a = 1 * x a = x

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main () {   
    int x1,a;
    char X;
    cout<< "ENTERO POR CHAR";
    cout<< "DIGITE EL VALOR DE X1: "; cin >> x1;
    a = x1 * X;
    cout << a;
    //Si se digita un 1 en x1 que salga en pantalla una x.
    //Si se digita un 2 en x1 que salga en pantalla un 2x.

    return 0;
}
```

Lo habia pensado con:

```
cout<< a << "x";
```

Pero si a es 1 no imprimiria x si 1x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes mirarlo así: Solo debes imprimir el valor almacenado en `x1` si el mismo es superior a 1 o, dicho con código:

```
if( x1 > 1 )
  std::cout << x1;
std::cout << 'x';
```

La `x` entiendo que debe imprimirse siempre, luego no tiene sentido incluirla en el `if`.

El programa completo:

```
int main () {   
    int x1;
    cout<< "ENTERO POR CHAR";
    cout<< "DIGITE EL VALOR DE X1: ";
    cin >> x1;

    if( x1 > 1 )
        cout << x1;
    cout << 'x';

    return 0;
}
```

Consideraciones sobre tu código:

- Si te piden imprimir un literal, que es un valor constante, no es necesario almacenarlo en una variable.
- Procura inicializar **todas** las variables al declararlas.
- Una variable de tipo numérico únicamente puede almacenar números, la operación `a=x1*X` no te va a permitir evaluar la ecuación sino que va a almacenar en `a` el resultado de multiplicar `x1` por `X` (en tu caso `X` no está inicializada).

Comment: Mmm creo que entiendo y lo voy a manejar de otra forma me diste una idea, en el libro que estoy aprendiendo me piden que saque la ecuacion de la recta de la forma ordinaria, y tenia que imprimi una literal por una x "caracter" y una x1 "entero" por una variable a "entero", creo que si al lado de x le sumo una variable de mas, y el condicional if que me pasaste podria solucionar el problema(es logico claro). Aunque como no he pasado acondicionares quería saber si había una función que hiciera esto. Muchas gracias eferion me ayudaste impresionantemente.

Answer (score 1):

Tu idea de imprimir

```
cout<<a<<"x";
```

esta bien, solo que tienes que utilizar condiciones de tal manera que si "a" es igual a 1 imprima "x" y si es diferente imprimir nx

```
cin>>a;
if(a==1)
    cout<<"x";
else
    cout<<a<<"x";
```

Ten en cuenta que al realizar esta operación

```
char X;
a=x1*X;
```

estas multiplicando el valor asociado a X (la variable) y no el valor del caracter 'x'. Como no inicializas el valor de la variable X, dependiendo del compilador, su valor puede variar. En mi caso X valia 0, por lo que a=x1*0 y eso hacia que el resultado fuera 0

Comment: Si me fije de ese problema, el resultado me daba 119, por el codigo ASCII. Gracias por la ayuda pero no hay una forma de multiplicar el entero por el caracter y que solo sume el entero sin utilizar el for?.

Comment: no entendi bien, multiplicar el entero por el caracter? tal vez lo que quieres es concatenar algo asi a=5+'x' y que a=5x

si es eso, si se puede, pero usas otro tipo de dato llamado string, tendrias que agregar #include<string> a tus librerias y hacer algo asi

string a=""; cin>>x1;
if(x1==1) a = "x";
else   a = to_string(x1) + "x";

tal vez aun no llegas a esa parte, pero si es posible. Lo dejo todo pegado, no se puede dar formato en comentarios